# PHP Word File line counter

Tags: php, html, file, count

I need to make a PHP function that will count the number of lines in a Word File (.doc, docx)

This code does not seem to work correctly for me :

```
 $name = 'test.doc';                
 $line_count = count(file($name));
 echo $line_count
```

My guess is  that this script does not work well with .doc or .docx but works good in .txt files. Are there any alternatives available out there? Tnx!

Comment: Uhmm, I don't think you can do that with a .doc file, as it is a Microsoft Office file and it's contents are not simple text.

Comment: I really hope you are not implying that there is no solution available  :((

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/read-pdf-doc-file-php maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Only `.docx` can be opened with simple `PHP` as it is a `zip` file:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.docx') === TRUE) {
    $xml = $zip->getFromName('docProps/app.xml');
    $zip->close();
} else {
    $xml = false;
}

if($xml){
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    echo $xml->Lines;
}
```